# jsPDF outputs blank document

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to save the output of a div on my page to PDF

My Code so far is:

```
function makepdf() {

var doc = new jsPDF();
var html=jQuery('.js-requester-info').html();
alert (html);
doc.fromHTML(html , 15, 15, {
    'width': 800
});

     doc.save('test');
}
```

The code works, but the generated PDF file is always blank.
I have added a "debug" line and

```
alert (html);
```

outputs some html code from the div, but how come the PDF is always empty?

UPDATE:
I added some delay ( I found someone talnkig about delay in rendering) and now it's working:

```
setTimeout(function(){
doc.save('test');
},2000);
```

Comment: Looks like adding some timeout make it work....

Comment: interesting, this post solved my problem. Any idea why adding timeout was necessary? and why it was not including in doc?

Comment: tried adding timeOut as well, but works on the last page only. the previous pages shows blank :(

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback option

```js
let doc = new JsPDF({ orientation: 'p', format: 'a4' })
console.log(document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML)
doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML, 1, 1, {
  elementHandlers: function() {
    return true
  }
}, function() {
  doc.save('test')
})
```